# Jquery, how to split() string and get the targeted string in the middle? e.g : sample_str[targeted_str][other_str]

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

http://jsfiddle.net/150aby4u/

I have multiple dropdowns, each of it have different field name which is incremented.

My goal is to get the middle part of the string/text after I make any changes to the dropdown. I would like to get the number at the middle which is `111`.

```
rank_item[111][rank]
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="rank" name="rank_item[0][rank]">
    <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
    <option value="1">Airman</option>
    <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>
<select class="rank" name="rank_item[1][rank]">
    <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
    <option value="1">Airman</option>
    <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('change keyup', '.rank', function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('name'))
    })
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression to extract digits before a `]`:

```
const num = this.name.match(/\d+(?=\])/)[0];
```

- `\d` - Match digits
- `(?=\])` - Until the next character is a `]`

```js
$(document).on('change keyup', '.rank', function() {
  const num = this.name.match(/\d+(?=\])/)[0];
  console.log(num)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="rank" name="rank_item[0][rank]">
  <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
  <option value="1">Airman</option>
  <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>
<select class="rank" name="rank_item[1][rank]">
  <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
  <option value="1">Airman</option>
  <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
</select>
```

Comment: wow that was fast, works like a charm...what is the key word to search for tutorial regarding this method? `(/\d+(?=\])/)`

Comment: I'd start [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=regular+expressions+tutorial), [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is a good site

Answer (score 1):

Simple regular expression:

```js
const str = "rank_item[111][rank]";
const [, num] = /\[(\d+)\]/.exec(str);
console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a proponent of magic numbers (breaks if "name" changes significantly), just pointing out you don't necessarily need a regex to do this:

```js
var str = "rank_item[16][rank]";
console.log(str.substring(10, str.length - 7));
```